Lilypond move Fine on top of staff
I would like to set Fine to the top of the staff, instead of bottom.
How to tell \fine marking to change position?
It is used inside of segno and ideally, Fine position could be further adjusted to fit inside of volta brackets, but even "on top" is enough for me.
Here is minimal full example:
\version "2.25.12"

\score {
    \relative d'' {
        \clef "treble" \time 4/4 \key f \major \transposition f | % 1
        c4 c4 c4 c4 |
        \repeat segno 2 {
            \repeat volta 2 {
                c4 c4 c4 c4 |
                \alternative {
                    \volta 1 { c4 c4 c4 c4 \bar ":|]" }
                    \volta 2 { c4 c4 \fine c4 c4 \bar "||" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



And not with 2.25.14 either.

It is best if you post working example code, but I think adding a tweak will get you what you want:
\tweak JumpScript.Y-offset 3 \fine


I did an edit, but this work exactly right. Thanks!
